# Issues with Power Query M POST Request in Power BI for Azure Key Vault Integration

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop, azure-keyvault, m, powerbi-datasource

**Problem:**

I am trying to retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault in Power BI using Power Query's M language. I need to make a POST request to the Azure AD token endpoint to obtain an access token, but I am encountering errors.

**Attempted Solution:**

Here is the code I have tried in Power Query:

Code Power Query M (Advanced Editor)

```
let
    GetKeyVaultSecret = (keyVaultUrl as text, secretName as text) =>
        let
            clientId = "your-client-id",
            clientSecret = "your-client-secret",
            tenantId = "your-tenant-id",
            tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" & tenantId & "/oauth2/token",
            apiUrl = keyVaultUrl & "/secrets/" & secretName & "?api-version=7.0",
            
            body = "grant_type=client_credentials" &
                   "&client_id=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(clientId) &
                   "&client_secret=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(clientSecret) &
                   "&resource=https://vault.azure.net",
            
            options = [
                Headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
                Content = Text.ToBinary(body)
            ],
            
            tokenRequest = Web.Contents(tokenUrl, options),
            tokenResponse = Json.Document(tokenRequest),
            accessToken = tokenResponse[access_token],
            
            secretRequest = Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers = [#"Authorization" = "Bearer " & accessToken]]),
            secretResponse = Json.Document(secretRequest),
            secretValue = secretResponse[value]
        in
            secretValue,

    SecretValue = GetKeyVaultSecret("https://your-key-vault-name.vault.azure.net", "your-secret-name")
in
    SecretValue
```

**Issue:**

When executing the code above, I encountered the following error:

[DataSource.Error] Web.Contents with the Content option is only supported when connecting anonymously.

**Additional Details:**

- I am using Power BI Desktop to retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault.
- I have verified that the client ID, client secret, and tenant ID are correct.
- I have ensured that the Azure AD application has the necessary permissions to access the Key Vault.
- I have tried various modifications to the code, including using the **`HttpClient`** class and different options for the request body, but the error persists.

**Desired Outcome:**

I would like to successfully make a POST request to the Azure AD token endpoint in Power Query within Power BI to retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault. I need assistance in resolving the "Web.Contents with the Content option is only supported when connecting anonymously" error or finding an alternative approach to achieve the desired integration.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!